# Count the number of Groups in a report in Salesforce

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, custom-reports

I am trying to create a report of Account and Orders where I am grouping by account to get the accounts with at least one order. I want to count the number of Accounts(which is number of groups) with at least one order. But as per my understanding of the idea below:
https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdemVUAR/create-the-ability-to-count-the-number-grouping-in-a-report

We can't count the number of groups in a summary report, so wanted to check is there any way to get the number of accounts with at least one order. I basically need it for conversion percentage as in how many account have been converted into an order. Can anybody guide me on how to do it?

Thanks in advance!